# Remove objects from array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have this function:

```
public function get_free_courtrooms() {
        $post = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $_POST = json_decode($post, true);

        $date = $this->input->post('date', true);
        $time_start = $this->input->post('time_start', true);
        $time_end = $this->input->post('time_end', true);

        $where = array('date' => $date);
        $reservations = $this->MY_Model->get('reservations', $where);

        $courtrooms = $this->MY_Model->get('courtrooms');

        $output = array(
            'free_courtrooms' => $free_courtrooms
        );

        echo json_encode($output);
        exit();
    }
```

I need to remove all courtrooms from $courtrooms that are booked in sending hours ($time_start, $time_end).

In reservations table I have:

- id
- courtroom_id
- date
- time_start
- time_end

Comment: Whaat the hell are _post hours_???

Comment: $time_start and $time_end

Comment: Just add a where clause conditioning `$time_start`, `$time_end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with simple function to check overlapping 2 time:

```
function isOverlap($s1, $e1, $s2, $e2) {
    return (($s1 > $s2 && $s1 < $e2) || ($e1 > $s2 && $e1 < $e2)
            || ($s1 < $s2 && $e1 > $2) || ($s1 > $s2 && $e1 < $e2));
}
```

This will be visualization of the 4 cases:

```
---     |    ---  |   -------   |     ---
  ---   |   ---   |     ---     |   -------
```

Now just fill array of all busy rooms:

```
foreach($reservations as $res) {
    if (isOverlap($time_start, $time_end, $res["start"], $res["end"]))
        $busy_courtrooms[] = $res["id"]; 
}
```

Now calculate the diff between all the `$courtrooms` and the `$busy_courtrooms` using [array-diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$free_courtrooms = array_diff($courtrooms, $busy_courtrooms);
```

And you done

I don't now how your `$reservations` array is build but I guess it has "start" and "end" attribute...

Comment: But I must return from this function list of all courtrooms that do not have a reservation. $free_courtrooms is all courtrooms that are not reservation during these hours.